# Can someone explain me the second part of this code please?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
let a = [101, 103, 222, 97, 105];

var i = 0;
a.forEach(function(v){
  v == 97 || v == 101 || v == 105 || v==111 || v ==117 ? a[i++] = String .fromCharCode(v) : a[i++] = v;}),a;


console.log(a);
```

result : [ 'e', 103, 222, 'a', 'i' ]

I do understand we are looping through the array and looking for any matching values and i know what the rest of the code does, but I don't understand the part after the `?`.

Comment: It is checking for every index in array and replace the current index with the char value of ascii given and then incrementing index.

example: index = 0; and v == 101 is true therefore, a[index] = char(101), which is 'e' and then deliberately incrementing index so now index = 1, but foreach loop will intern increment index, so a[1] is left as it is and now index = 2. and so on

Comment: The true part of the ternary operator is storing the value of characters corresponding to the current index while the false part is just storing the number.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is just a weird (or minified) way of saying:

```js
if (v == 97 || v == 101 || v == 105 || v==111 || v ==117) {
    a[i] = String.fromCharCode(v); // The character represented by the number v. e.g 97 => 'a'
} else {
    a[i] = v; // The number v without any conversion
}
i++;
```

Comment: Thank you. but if we were to write that way, we would need to do a for loop before the if statement right?

Comment: It can stay in the same place - the `.forEach` already acts as a loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking for vowels code in an array, if it matches it replaces with the text representation else the number.

Simplified version of your code (if you understand **this**)-

```js
let a = [101, 103, 222, 97, 105];

a.forEach(function(v, i){ 
   this[i] = (v == 97 || v == 101 || v == 105 || v==111 || v ==117) ? String.fromCharCode(v) : v;
}, a);

console.log(a);
```

Your code is having - `a[i++] = v;}),a;` I think `,a` is referring to the second argument of `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this. Basically some numbers get replaced with chars.

```js
let a = [101, 103, 222, 97, 105];

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if ([97, 101, 105, 111, 117].includes(a[i])) {
    // Replace int with char
    a[i] = String.fromCharCode(a[i])
  }
}

console.log(a);
```